# Why is there no Potential Function of this vector field.

Tags: functions, derivatives

$$F=2xy^2z^2i+2xy^2z^2j+2xy^2z^2k$$ Solve for the potential function. $$\frac{df}{dx}=2xy^2z^2;df=\int_{x}2xy^2z^2=x^2y^2z^2+Q$$
$$\frac{df}{dy}=2xy^2z^2;df=\int_{y}2xy^2z^2=\frac{2}{3}xy^3z^2+Q$$
$$\frac{df}{dx}=2xy^2z^2;df=\int_{z}2xy^2z^2=\frac{2}{3}xy^2z^3+Q$$

The answer is that there is NO Potential function at all. Why is the answer there is No function, but not: $$x^2y^2z^2+\frac{2}{3}xy^3z^2+\frac{2}{3}xy^2z^3$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always see if a function $f$ is a potential for a vector field $F$ by checking whether $F = \nabla f$. (That's not the case for your vector field and function. As for why there's _no_ potential, have you seen the curl operator, and the identify $\nabla \times (\nabla f) = 0$?) Not sure what your second question is asking.

Comment: !!! I forgot to check for conservative field first!! Thanks!  I copied the question wrong for the second part. So i'm going to edit it out. This is embarrassing. Thanks for your help!.